# Onload of Jquery show the total Values first

Tags: jquery, json

Want to show the total values of the **visitors, Sales and transaction** from json inside the div first and then to change based on the drop down selection.

> for eg:- onload of the page.. **show total values of Visitors, Sales and Transaction**
>
> **When selecting the first drop-down.. like Asia.. Show only the total values of Asia (which is achieved in the fiddle)**

also, when value is selected in first drop-down.. **second, third and fourth drop-down** should show a **default value** like **select** instead of displaying values immediately.  how to achieve this???

fiddle for the work up-to now

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/d9f8t9vj/9/`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the the option first to the select which you want to make it as default. Set its value to default. hen just set value of that element to default using .val("default");

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Yes it will be possible to update fiddle.